# Is it possible to implement the __super macro?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, gcc, macros

Please tell me if there is a way to manually implement the Microsoft specific **__super** macro...

Comment: Please let us know what the __super macro does.

Comment: Actually `__super` is not a macro, but a keyword - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/94dw1w7x(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: @Neil: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/94dw1w7x.aspx

Comment: do you have an specific use case that you want to solve? In general, the complexity of providing a full blown `__super` implementation with user code will be too much, but if you are concerned on a particular use case, it might not be that complex.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
class Base{
public:
  void func(){
    // something
  }
};

class Derived : public Base{
public:
  void func(){
    Base::func(); // just use the base class name
  }
};
```

Though I assume that's not what you want and you want a generic access for every class? I don't know of a direct solution, but you can always `typedef` your immediate base class:

```
class Derived : public Base{
  typedef Base super; // typedef accordingly in every class
public:
  void func(){
    super::func();
  }
};
```

Or even have an intermediate class just for the typedef if you really want..

```
template<class Base>
struct AddSuper : public Base {
protected:
  typedef Base super;
};

class Derived : public AddSuper<Base> {
public:
  void func(){
    super::func();
  }
};
```

Note that you should not forget to retypedef in every derived class, else you'll get holes in your call-chain.

One drawback: The whole construct blows up with multiple base classes. :/

Comment: @Ryan: A nice sideeffect from the typedef is, that you can use it in the initializer list instead of the (possibly long) base class name. :)

Comment: I've used the `typedef` trick (without the additional intermediate) a few times when inheriting from classes with template arguments. DRY at work... (or almost, since you need to repeat yourself once).

Comment: @Matthieu: I generally do this for the current class with `this_type` or `self_type` or like MSVC `MyType`, especially if it's templated. It also brings a nice uniformity to all my operators. :) Also, I consider templated classes usually unusable without such a typedef.

Answer (score 3):

Avoid it, it makes your code unportable. If you want to have a short name for your base class then use a typedef:

```
class Derived: public BaseWithALongName
{
   typedef BaseWithALongName super;
};
```

Answer (score 3):

A keyword `super` was actually proposed a long while back in the C++ standardisation process,but it was rejected as unnecessary, as it could be implemented using the method described by Xeo in his answer - this is covered in Stroustrup's D&E book. I guess Microsoft decided it really is necessary, but be warned if you use it your code will not be portable.

Comment: One good thing from the `__super` keyword that you can't emulate is that it considers all base classes.

Comment: @Xeo: it is a matter of making the code a little more cumbersome... you can write an adapter template that will inherit from all of the base classes and adds a `using X::func;` for each base class `X`. Then the most derived class need only inherit from that adapter. If you call it `super` then the syntax: `super::func` will dispatch to the immediate parent, that will have the `using` declarations and will consider all base classes. Still too much complexity for little to no gain.

Comment: @David: That's an interesting idea though, thanks for that. But you're right. You can't have such an adaptor as a simple mixin, it needs to be hand-coded for every hierarchy. :/