# Trouble verifying that my super class or base class is what a macro or template claims it to be

Tags: c++, inheritance, macros, clang

I've been dealing with a frustrating problem recently. I have a lot of reflection code I'd like to hide in macros. These `COMPONENT_x()` macros are used to like so:

```
class ComponentBase : public IComponent
{
    COMPONENT(ComponentBase)
};

class ComponentDerived1 : public ComponentBase
{
    COMPONENT_DERIVED(ComponentDerived1, ComponentBase)
};
```

The above is completely valid. However, I would like a compile error to occur in this case:

```
class ComponentDerived2 : public ComponentDerived1
{
    COMPONENT_DERIVED(ComponentDerived2, ComponentBase)
    //                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    // This type claims to have a superclass of ComponentBase in the above macro,
    // but we really derive from ComponentDerived1.
    //
    // I want this to result in a compile error. 
};
```

That is, when I'm claiming that my super class (or my base class) is `ComponentBase` when my the super class is actually `ComponentDerived1`, I would ideally like a compile-time error.

The reason I cannot easily detect this case is that while my super class is `ComponentDerived1`, that class' super is `ComponentBase` — and thus it is also one of my base classes. (I understand that `ComponentDerived1` is-a `ComponentBase`, so maybe there is a better phrase to use than "base class.")

There were some comments questioning why I want to do this. I'm using an optimized system of component generation which puts all objects of the same type into discrete buffers, so generating knowledge of class relationships is important if I want to have an API such as `getComponentsThatImplement(ComponentDerived1::getType());`.

I had hacked together [one solution](http://codepad.org/zHEdiMDQ) that works with g++:

```
class ComponentBase : public IComponent
{
    COMPONENT(ComponentBase)

protected:
    static void helperComponentBase(); // COMPONENT(ComponentBase)
};

class ComponentDerived1 : public ComponentBase
{
    COMPONENT_DERIVED(ComponentDerived1, ComponentBase)

private:
    using ComponentBase::helperComponentBase; // COMPONENT_DERIVED(..., ComponentBase)
};

class ComponentDerived2 : public ComponentDerived1
{
    COMPONENT_DERIVED(ComponentDerived2, ComponentBase)

private:
    using ComponentBase::helperComponentBase; // error: this function is already hidden
}
```

Unfortunately, clang with Xcode 4.3.2 seems to not support `using` in this way. I've check boost's type traits library and don't see anything useful. I am using C++11, so I can use modern constructs.

Any other clever ideas?

Comment: So what are the `COMPONENT_X` macros for? Could you post their definition?

Comment: What is the point of these macros?  It seems like you're just immediately re-expressing the explicit inheritance relationship in the form of a macro; I don't see how this helps you.

Comment: You should explain what you are actually trying to obtain from the macro. BTW, the whole *I want to hide in macros* goal seems... well probably not the best idea. What do you intend on expressing with those macros?

Comment: I'm not convinced that the usage of macros deserves  __too__ much scrutiny here since a templated member variable will have similar problems.

The macros create functions like `getType()` and `getTypeName()`. There are other options here but the point of this implementation is to avoid cache misses for performance. (This is for an iPhone game.)

I've posted the macros here: http://codepad.org/l5mfhWMh

Comment: @ildjarn It's true that I'm not attempting to use polymorphism, though I am not misunderstanding it and I do address your point in my post — down to the phrase "`ComponentDerived1` is-a `ComponentBase`."

Comment: Ok, so it seems that the key thing here is that the resulting `getSuperType()` function returns the correct `Type` (whatever that is).  So you're looking for a way to enforce that?

Comment: Fair enough, I didn't read your post thoroughly. I should have said "misusing inheritance" rather than polymorphism. I'm still unclear as to what you're trying to achieve that couldn't be solved with mixins; i.e., it seems to me that your problem is caused by having more than one tier in the inheritance chain.

Comment: @ildjarn I'm using an optimized system of component generation which puts all objects of the same type into discrete buffers, so generating knowledge of class relationships is important if I want to `getComponentsThatImplement(ComponentDerived1::getType());`. Which I do. :)

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Yes, I want a `getBaseType()` that reports my super class' type (i.e. `super::getType()`).

Comment: That could be done statically with type lists (see e.g. [Boost.MPL](http://www.boost.org/libs/mpl/)); still no obvious need for inheritance.

Comment: @ildjarn some types of components _will_ implement interfaces and as such require inheritance (there is also a `COMPONENT_ABSTRACT`). For a variety of reasons, I do not consider boost suitable as a wholesale replacement for my implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can exploit the fact that from a c'tor you cannot directly call your super's super's c'tor:

```
enum PATERNITY_TEST_ENUM { PATERNITY_TEST }; 

#define COMPONENT(CLASS) \
public: CLASS(PATERNITY_TEST_ENUM) { } private:

#define COMPONENT_DERIVED(CLASS, SUPER) \
public: CLASS(PATERNITY_TEST_ENUM) : SUPER(PATERNITY_TEST) { } private:
```

Comment: This is a great idea, and I forgot about this constraint. Notably, this will prevent default constructors from being generated, but with C++11 we can prevent that with `CLASS() = default;`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is too  much of a hack for your taste, but it might do the trick. Tested in vs 2010. You would need to fold the static functions into your reflection macros.

This creates an error on `ComponentDerrived2`: `ComponentDerived1::__ComponentBase : cannot access private member declared in class ComponentDerived1`

```
class IComponent {
};

class ComponentBase : public IComponent
{
    //COMPONENT(ComponentBase)
protected:
    static void __ComponentBase() { };
};

class ComponentDerived1 : public ComponentBase
{
    //COMPONENT_DERIVED(ComponentDerived1, ComponentBase)
protected:
    static void __ComponentDerived1() { __super::__ComponentBase(); };
private:
    static void __ComponentBase() { };
public:

};

class ComponentDerived2 : public ComponentDerived1
{
    //COMPONENT_DERIVED(ComponentDerived2, ComponentBase)
protected:
    static void __ComponentDerived2() { __super::__ComponentBase(); }
private:
    static void __ComponentBase() { };
public:

};
```

Comment: `__super` is a VC++ extension, so it won't be very helpful for the OP's iPhone game.

Comment: Unfortunately `__super` is [not available on my platform](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6041100/is-it-possible-to-implement-the-super-macro). With `__super`, you can use `is_same` ([boost docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/is_same.html)). Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely use type_traits for this. Throw in a compile-time assert and you'll have it. Here's some code that should work:

```
#define PARENTCHECKER_THING(__TYPE,__BASE)                     \
inline void WastedFunc()                                       \
    { COMPILE_ASSERT( (std::is_base_of<__BASE,__TYPE>().value == true) ); }


#define COMPONENT(__TYPE)                                               \
    bool __TYPE##SomeFunc(bool val) { return val; }                     \
    bool __TYPE##SomeOtherThing(bool val) { return val; }

#define COMPONENT_DERIVED(__TYPE,__BASE)                                \       
    bool __TYPE##SomeFunc( bool val) { return val; }                    \
    bool __TYPE##SomeOtherThing(bool val) { return val; }               \
    PARENTCHECKER_THING(__TYPE,__BASE);

class Base
{
    COMPONENT(Base);
    int baseData;
};

class NOT_Base
{
    COMPONENT(NOT_Base);
    int garbage;
};

class Child : public Base
{
protected:
    COMPONENT_DERIVED(Child,NOT_Base);

    float childData;
};
```

Admittedly, the base checker only needs to some base class and not the *immediate* base. I suppose I could have also been a little more clever about not adding a bogus function in there. It should be dead-stripped though.

Hope this helps!

EDIT: Hmmm...I missed the sentance in the middle where you called this out as a problem. How about this then:

```
#define PARENTCHECKER_THING(__TYPE,__BASE)                     \
inline void WastedFunc()                                       \
    { COMPILE_ASSERT( (std::is_same< std::common_type<__BASE,__TYPE>()::type, __BASE >().value == true) ); }
```

Essentially, "Assert if the common type of the base and the child is something other than the base".
Unfortunately, I don't have a copy of VS2010 handy, and VS2008 doesn't support common_type<>.

Comment: This will work for many cases, but in the exact case I have above it will fail. `is_base_of<ComponentBase, ComponentDerived2,>::value` is true. I'm really looking for a `is_parent_class_of` or `is_super_class_of`. :)

Comment: Yeah, I saw that shortly after I posted initially. Damn my skimming eyes!
Ok...edit edit edit...how's that? :-)

Comment: Hmm, I think this will work. However: 1. C++11's stdlib doesn't seem to be in a working state in Xcode, so I can't use standard library features; and, 2. clang doesn't currently seem to support decltype and I can't use boost, so I don't think I can actually get this to work for me. :(

Comment: Yeah...upon reflection, it's really no better than just using _is_base_of<>.

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is to change your classes to derive from a template argument. That way, you actually have a way to reference the base-type name.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty simple way of doing this, maybe I am missing something, but couldn't you just stub in a dummy function (that you will never use) that raises the compiler error with simple pointer assignment:

```
#define COMPONENT_DERIVED(__TYPE,__BASE) \
    // your code here                    \
    void ensureBase()                    \
    {                                    \
         // compiler error:              \
         __BASE* foo = this;             \
         // to ensure __TYPE as well:    \
         __TYPE* bar = this;             \
         // to prevent compiler warning: \
         foo = bar;                      \
    }
```

Comment: This will compile for the example above when I don't want it to compile.